# For Each Loop with ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, foreach, nested

In the below code, how is it that in the inner For Each loop, we can create a variable of type int from the variable we created in the outer For Each loop that is of type List? Yet if we try to create this variable of primitive type int, there is an error. Can't work out how we can create a For Each variable of type int from userAge, but not from userAges.

```
   List <List<Integer>> userAges = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    userAges.add(Arrays.asList(51, 48, 21));
    userAges.add(Arrays.asList(33, 51, 19));
    userAges.add(Arrays.asList(39, 47, 58));

    for (List<Integer> userAge : userAges)
    {
        for (int age : userAge)
        {
            System.out.print(age + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Because `int age : userAge` can be read as "*for each `int age` in `userAge` do ...*". It really is just the same as the outer loop, where one interates over all `List<Integer> userAge` in `List<List<Integer>> userAges`.

Comment: Not sure if I understand "how we can create a For Each variable of type int from userAge, but not from userAges" correctly... `userAges` is a List containing Lists, so  a single entry would be of type List, not of type Integer: `List<Integer> firstEntry = userAges.get(0)`. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

Java will *auto-unbox* the primitive wrapper classes to their primitive equivalent, so given

```
List<Integer> userAge; // what the outer loop provides to the inner loop
```

We can write either:

```
for (Integer age : userAge)
```

or:

```
for (int age : userAge)
```

More generally, given:

```
Integer integer;
```

We can write:

```
int i = integer;
```

Read the full specification [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).